# Haskell replace an item in a existing list

Tags: haskell

Im trying to create a function that replace a given existing place with a new place

```
data Place =  Place String Coord [Int] 
             deriving (Ord,Eq,Show,Read)

data Coord =  Cord Double Double
             deriving (Ord ,Eq ,Show ,Read)


testData :: [Place]
testData = [ Place "London"       (Cord 51.5  (-0.1))   [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0], 
             Place"Cardiff"      (Cord 51.5  (-3.2))   [12, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0, 2],
             Place"Norwich"      (Cord 52.6  (1.3) )   [0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3], 
             Place "Birmingham"   (Cord 52.5  (-1.9))   [0, 2, 10, 7, 8, 2, 2],
             Place"Liverpool"    (Cord 53.4  (-3.0))   [8, 16, 20, 3, 4, 9, 2],
             Place "Hull"         (Cord 53.8  (-0.3))   [0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4],
             Place "Newcastle"    (Cord 55.0  (-1.6))   [0, 0, 8, 3, 6, 7, 5],
             Place "Belfast"      (Cord 54.6  (-5.9))   [10, 18, 14, 0, 6, 5, 2],
             Place "Glasgow"      (Cord 55.9  (-4.3))   [7, 5, 3, 0, 6, 5, 0],
             Place"Plymouth"     (Cord 50.4  (-4.1))   [4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5],
             Place "Aberdeen"     (Cord 57.1  (-2.1))   [0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 2, 0],
             Place "Stornoway"    (Cord 58.2  (-6.4))   [15, 6, 15, 0, 0, 4, 2],
             Place"Lerwick"      (Cord 60.2  (-1.1))    [8, 10, 5, 5, 0, 0, 3],
             Place"St Helier"    (Cord 49.2  (-2.1))     [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0] ]
```

```
replaceLocate :: String -> Place  -> [Place] -> [Place]
replaceLocate _ _ []             = []
replaceLocate  str  (Place l d rains) ((Place p c rain):xs)
      | str == p             = Place l d rains : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs 
      | otherwise            = Place p c rain  : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs
```

while using String to search for the Places that I wanted to change.

But it gives me this error :

```
Smth.hs:96:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Place’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Place
    • In the pattern: Place l d rains
      In an equation for ‘replaceLocate’:
          replaceLocate str (Place l d rains) ((Place p c rain) : xs)
            | str == p
            = Place l d rains : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs
            | otherwise
            = Place p c rain : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs
   |
96 | replaceLocate  str  (Place l d rains) ((Place p c rain):xs)    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Smth.hs:97:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Place’
      Expected type: Place
        Actual type: String
    • In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘p’
      In the expression: str == p
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘replaceLocate’:
        str == p
   |
97 |       | str == p             = Place l d rains : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs     |                ^

Smth.hs:97:82: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Place’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Place
    • In the second argument of ‘replaceLocate’, namely ‘str’
      In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
        ‘replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs’
      In the expression:
        Place l d rains : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs
   |
97 |       | str == p             = Place l d rains : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs     |                                                                                  ^^^

Smth.hs:98:86: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Place’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Place
    • In the second argument of ‘replaceLocate’, namely ‘str’
      In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
        ‘replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs’
      In the expression:
        Place p c rain : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs
   |
98 |           | otherwise            = Place p c rain  : replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs    |                                                                                      ^^^
```

Comment: Im trying to replace the old place (Place p c rain) with new place  (Place l d rains ) eg: (London ( 51 (0,1) [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ) to (Shefield (42,32)[3,3,2,13,1......]), while the string is just me to search the elem London  so I can change it to the new one

Comment: I try to replace a given existing place with a new place ?

Answer (score 2):

In your recurve call you are swapping the first two parameters. You need to replace this:

```
replaceLocate (Place l d rains) str xs
```

With this:

```
replaceLocate str (Place l d rains) xs
```